# Merge two list of strings based on a condition

Tags: python, list, merge

I'm trying to create a function to merge two lists and return the sorted output based on year that only contains the tags I wanted, for example:

```
InputLists = [List1, List2]

List1 = ["2010 11 A", "2011 15 B", "2007 19 A", "2012 16 C"]
List2 = ["2015 8 A", "2016, 7 C", "2011 4 B"]



TagLists = ["A", "C"]

sorted_output = my_function(InputLists, TagLists)

sorted_output = ["2007 19 A", "2010 11 A", "2012 16 C", "2015 8 A", "2016 7 C"]
```

What would such a function look like?

Comment: The function would start with a line `def my_function(input_lists, tag_lists)`: and then there would be some indented statements which would maybe concatenate all the lists and then call either the list `sort` method or the `sorted` function where a function is passed as the `key` parameter in order to sort the list according to the contents of `tag_lists`.

Comment: Something like: `sorted([e for e in l1 + l2 if e[-1] in tags], key=lambda x: int(x[:4]))`.

Comment: [I downvoted your question because no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function should work:

```
def my_function(il, tl):
  combined = il[0] + il[1] #combine both input lists
  filtered = [] #create filtered list
  for val in combined: #iterate through elements in combined list
    if val[-1] in tl: #checking if last letter is in tagged list
      filtered.append(val) #if so, add to filtered list
  filtered.sort(key = lambda x: (int)(x[:4])) #sort by year
  return filtered #returning filtered list (our answer)



List1 = ["2010 11 A", "2011 15 B", "2007 19 A", "2012 16 C"]
List2 = ["2015 8 A", "2016, 7 C", "2011 4 B"]
InputLists = [List1, List2]


TagLists = ["A", "C"]

sorted_output = my_function(InputLists, TagLists)

print(sorted_output)
```

Output:

```
['2007 19 A', '2010 11 A', '2012 16 C', '2015 8 A', '2016, 7 C']
```

First, we combine the two lists of our `InputLists`, `List1` and `List2`. Then, we create a filtered list that will only add elements of `combined` if the last letter is in `tl`, our `TagLists`. Then, we just sort by the year, or by the integer value of the first 4 characters of each element.

Let me know if you need any further help or clarifications! :)

Comment: How do we handle the white spaces in the strings?

Answer (score 0):

if you have only two lists you can replace `InputLists = [List1, List2]` with `InputLists = List1 + List2` and then use:

```
def is_contain_tag(input, tags):
    for tag in tags:
        if tag in input:
            return True
    return False

def my_function(InputLists, TagLists):
    return sorted([input for input in InputLists if is_contain_tag(input, TagLists)])
```

also, if you know that the tag is the last character, you can replace `is_contain_tag` with:

```
def is_contain_tag(input, tags):
    return len(input) > 1 and input[-1] in tags
```

also note, that if you don't know if the year apear at the beginning, you need to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

This will work with any number of lists of strings within the list that is given to the `lists` parameter and with any number of strings of various length and characters that are given as a list to the `tags` parameter. Any tag is considered to be separated from the rest of the string by a whitespace.

```
def fun(lists,tags):
    flat_list=[]
    result=[]
    for i in lists: #making one-level list
        flat_list+=i
    for i in flat_list:
        if any(i.endswith(' '+tag)==True for tag in tags):
            result[:0]=[i] #adding to the beginning
        else:
            result.append(i) #adding to the end
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what the function will look like. The code should use a loop to iterate over the tag list to check if the individual tags are in the two lists, that's why both the two lists for loops are under the one for the tag list

```
def merge_list(lst1,lst2,Taglist):
        sorted_output =[]
        for x in range(len(Taglist)):# loop for the tag list
            for j in range(len(lst1)):# loop for the list 1 
                if Taglist[x] in lst1[j]:#this compares items
                    sorted_output.append(lst1[j])
            for i in range(len(lst2)):# loop for the list 2 
                if Taglist[x] in lst2[i]:#this compares items
                    sorted_output.append(lst2[i])
        sorted_output = sorted(sorted_output)
        return sorted_output
            
    List1 = ["2010 11 A", "2011 15 B", "2007 19 A", "2012 16 C"]
    List2 = ["2015 8 A", "2016, 7 C", "2011 4 B"]
    TagLists = ["A", "C"]
    x =  merge_list(List1,List2,TagLists)
    print(x)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Comment: This should work regardless of the length of both lists